# ERROR:There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first. Multiple Users

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-7, datareader, sqldataadapter

I have an asp.net C# application (.net 4.0) connected to SQL Server 2012 using ADO.Net and am encountering an error which says:

[InvalidOperationException: There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first.]

I very well know what a DataReader is but, my problem is getting this error in below conditions:

- I have not at all used any DataReader in my application, I have only
  used DataAdapters everywhere. The code works fine while running in
  local environment and there is no errors.
- Application works fine even after deployment in IIS7 when used by a
  single user.
- **The error only occurs when multiple users starts using the website hosted in IIS7.**

Kindly help, I am also doubting for any problems with my hosting in IIS7

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of trial and error, finally I found out that it's a problem with SqlConnections. What I used to do was open a connection at the instantiation of my DAL layer object. So, whenever two methods from the same DAL object called together, it used to throw the error. 
I solved it by opening and closing a connection in every call to the database. **Now it all works fine**. This also allows max number of users to use the application at a time. Below is my code sample from DAL:-

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();

try
{
    using (SqlConnection sqlcon = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnectionString"].ToString()))
    {
        if (sqlcon.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            sqlcon.Open();

        SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand
        {
            Connection = sqlcon,
            CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure,
            CommandText = "MyStoredProc"
        };

        sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Parameter1", Parameter1);

        using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCommand))
        {
            adapter.Fill(dt);
        }
    }
    return dt;
}
catch (Exception exp)
{
    LogHelper.LogError(string.Concat("Exception Details: ", ExceptionFormatter.WriteExceptionDetail(exp)));
    throw exp;
}
finally
{
    dt.Dispose();
}
```

Please post a better way of doing it if you know any, thank you.